# Github pages not showing images

Tags: html, image, github-pages

I've set up my github pages at lii2.github.io, and I can link it to the css file in my repo. But although I've uploaded a simple image to my repo, the page is not displaying the image. I'm sure I've written the html correctly, and I've double checked for capitalization so I would very much appreciate any help.

The code is up on https://github.com/lii2/lii2.github.io the index.html file.

Comment: You've not written the html correctly (see answer of Mansoorkhan Cherupuzh). How did you achieve your level of "sure"? Did you use a validator or something? I recommend using the polyglot syntax, i.e. add namespace declaration and use EmptyElemTags for auto-closing empty elements, then you can use an XML Parser to perform such syntax checking.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. I had rewritten the page a couple of times before and each time I fixed a minor problem. Do you know a notepad ++ plugin that can validate an html page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error on Line Number 14

Change

```
<div class="content-container>
```

to

```
<div class="content-container">
```